# How to get a variable from array when getting response from API call?

Tags: php

After successfully logging in for a 3rd party API access, using the following code:

```
$response = Requests::post('https://apidomain.com/v3/account/login/api', $headers, $data);
```

When I print:

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($response); echo '</pre>';
```

I get the following:

```
Requests_Response Object
(
    [body] => {"access_token":"blabla",".issued":"2019-07-30T02:47:14.4326684Z",".expires":"2019-08-01T02:47:14.4326686Z"}
    [raw] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
etc...
```

Now I want to access the access_token as a variable so that I can pass for further processing.

I tried to access like: `$access_token=$response[body'] and $access_token=$response[1][body']`

Unfortunately nothing worked.

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Because `json_decode()` expects a 2nd parameter `true` to decode as an array. In that case, you access it as `$foo->access_token` or add `true` as a second parameter and access it as an array.

Comment: I could not get it...could u please let me know the syntax how to get? Because using json_decode() itself returning error as: Cannot use object of type Requests_Response as array

Comment: Going off the comment before, your syntax would be `$token = json_decode($response, true)['access_token']`. You was missing the second parameter, `true` to make it an array.

Comment: when I use ```$token = json_decode($response, true)['access_token']``` i get : ```json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string```

Comment: If `$response` is already an object, use `$response->access_token`, no need to decode it again

Comment: Incidentally using: ```$token = json_decode(json_encode($response), true)['body'] ```returns: ```{"access_token":"eyJhbG",".issued":"2019-07-30T03:48:48.7743017Z",".expires":"2019-08-01T03:48:48.7743018Z"}``` Now I need to access access_token as a variable

Comment: Decode that again and use `['access_token']`

Comment: I don't understand why you guide OP to use the hard way. `$response` is an object, you can access the body with `$response->body`. Just simply `$token = json_decode($response->body, true)['access_token']`

Comment: Yes @catcon. Thanks this was straight forward. This is what I was looking as an answer. Thanks

Comment: I was going off, now deleted comments from previous people to explain `json_decode()`, not the why isn't this code working question @catcon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @catcon 's proposal, I could use the following code and get it worked:

```
$token = json_decode($response->body, true)['access_token']; echo $token;
```